# Adicionar valor do produto na compra

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Bom galera eu to com a seguinte dificuldade, eu tenho um painel bem simples de venda : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como da pra ver eu tenho um combobox com alguns produtos nele , meu problema e o seguinte eu precisaria que assim que eu escolhesse qualquer um dos produtos ali , automaticamente em **VALOR** aparecesse o valor do produto que esta gravado na minha tabela , e se caso na quantidade eu escolhesse algum valor maior que 1 no **Valor Total** aparecesse o valor somado na quantidade exata.

Minha tabela : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo funcional, cabe a você adaptar para seu caso:

Select puxando todas as empresas do banco, chama um evento no **onchange** que vai preencher os inputs conforme os valores buscados no banco:

```
  <select class="select" id="numEmpresa" name="numEmpresa" onchange='empresa(this.value,this.id)' autofocus required>
     <option value='-1'>Digite N&ordm; da Empresa</option>
      <?php  foreach($empresas as $row){  ?> 
      <option value='<?=$row['num_empresa']?>'>
      <?=$row['num_empresa']?> - <?=$row['nm_empresa']?>
     </option> 
     <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

O evento  **onchange**  empresa, pega o valor do select e preenche o input **honorarios**

```
 <!-- Buscar Empresas -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function empresa(id,select){
      $('#honorario').attr("disabled",false);
      $.post("autoCompleteSelect.php",{idEsc:id},function(retorno){
          $('#honorarios').val(retorno);
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
    <!-- ./ Buscar Empresas -->
```

Preenche o input de acordo com o retorno da função:

```
<input type="text" id="honorarios" name="honorarios" >
```

O Script **(autoCompleteSelect.php)** que é chamado dentro do evento **empresa**, puxa do banco o valor do input **honorarios** e retorna para função

```
$id = (int)$_POST['idEsc']; // id passado pelo select

list($resultados,$quantidade) = $select->selectTable('empresa','valor',NULL,"numero=".$id,NULL);

if($quantidade>0){
    foreach ($resultados as $row) {
        $dados = str_replace(".",",", $row['valor']);
    }
}else{
    $dados = '';
}

echo $dados;
```

Comment: Opa Bia , me desculpe pela a demora a responder , mas você poderia me  dar uma explicação de como utilizar esse código ? tentei aqui algumas vezes mas não consegui adaptar

Comment: @MatheusGoes A primeira parte trata-se do select que tem os nomes das empresas, conforme a empresa que seleciono o valor do campo do honorário (input honorarios) é preenchido de acordo com o valor puxado do banco.

O script onchange é responsável por invocar o select (autoCompleteSelect.php) que faz a busca no banco.

O autoCompleteSelect.php é um arquivo separado, nele voce tem acesso ao banco e busca os elementos necessário, no caso o valor de honorário para preencher os inputs honorarios.

Comment: @MatheusGoes amigo sei que minha resposta ficou muito direta, assista esse vídeo que faz a mesma coisa desse script: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4HMjjPj5IU, tenho certeza que assim conseguirá.

Comment: Muito obg , consegui fazer seguindo essa video aula :)

Answer (score 0):

Essa função faz o seguinte: Cada vez que você altera ali no combobox ele exibe o valor que você selecionou, Desta forma você pode trocar ao invés de exibir você faz ele mostrar o valor do produto. Simples porem muito útil. Espero que ajude a você e a todos que estão com a mesma dificuldade.

```
<hmtl>
  <script>
    function b(){
      var i = document.f.estado.selectedIndex;
     // alert(document.f.estado[i].text);
     document.getElementById('valor').value = document.f.estado[i].text;
    }
  </script>
 <body>
  <form name="f">
    <select name="estado" onchange="b()">
     <option value="pd1">produto1</option>
     <option value="pd2">Produto2</option>
     <option value="pd3">produto3</option>
    </select>
  </form>

 <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" value="">

 </body>
</html>
```

para preencher o input é só usar:
document.getElementById('valor').value = document.f.estado[i].text;

onde o "valor" é  o id do input,  e  .value = "aqui é oque seria colocado no input".

Comment: Opa tentei aqui , mais nao era assim que eu queria , gostaria que o valor do produto fosse para dentro do 'input valor' e nao em um alert

Comment: Sim esse foi um exemplo de como você poderia fazer, Para você preencher o input é só fazer assim > document.getElementById('valor').value = "Valoresss";
Obvio que você trocaria o "Valoresss" para o valor do produto que você recebe do php.